# setting scrollLeft within a timer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a very strange bug. Im trying to limit the amount of scroll calls within a jquery mousewheel function. I have set a timer to limit the calls but it doesnt seem to call the function scrollLeft. However, it works if its not wrapped in any timer. Is this some kind of native JS bug? or has anyone found a workaround for it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrpos=0;
    var limitTimer;
    var did= true;

    $('html, body, *').bind('mousewheel', function(event,delta){

        var BODY= this;

        if (did){
            did =false;


            if (delta > 0) {
                if (scrpos >= $(document).width() - $(window).width()){

                    }else{
                    scrpos += 100;
                }

            } else {
                if (scrpos !== 0){
                    scrpos -= 100;
                }
            }


            BODY.scrollLeft = scrpos;
            console.log(scrpos);



            var limitTimer = setTimeout(function(){

                did=true;
                clearTimeout(limitTimer);

            }, 150);

        }
        //Works here when outside the call
        //BODY.scrollLeft = scrpos;



    });
 });
```

Comment: What browser are you using to test this? And also, why do you assign the event to `html`, `body` AND to everything (`*`)?

Comment: That selector scares me....

Comment: IM using Chrome and FireFox. The reason for that event is to cover the scroll function for Firefox, since its a known bug that firefox does not work with simple html, body. Therefore im using the (*).

Comment: There may be a scope issue with `limitTimer`.